# XPath find by text containing quotes

Tags: javascript, xpath, browser, domxpath

Consider a text containing both single and double quotes. I am storing it in a JS literal string

```js
const sampleText = `Uses the "crow's foot" notation rather than classic ER notation to depict a relationship`
```

I need to find the div element which contains this text.
I am using [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) function

```js
const xpath = `//div[text()="${sampleText}"]`
document
    .evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
    .iterateNext();
```

But the function call throws not a valid XPath.
Tried adding `escaped blackslash` `\\` before `double quotes` `"` in `sampleText` but no luck.
Failed attempt:

```
const sampleText = `Uses the \\"crow's foot\\" notation rather than classic ER notation to depict a relationship`
```

Error:

```
Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div/text()="Uses the \"crow's foot\" notation rather than classic ER notation to depict a relationship"' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Also other answers couldn't help as my string contains both double and single quotes and need code in JS

Comment: why two backslashes?

Comment: Double quotes inside a sting literal will be literal quotes but wanted to escape them before passing it to xpath evaluator, Thus escaping the backslash to result in escaped double quote when being evaluated by xpath

Comment: All these were just my assumptions and probably xpath doesn't escape anything , ie doesnt respect backslash

Comment: did you try escaping with only 1 backslash?

Comment: Yup. ` The string '//div[text()="Uses the "crow's foot" notation rather than classic ER notation to depict a relationship"]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Use the `concat` function and separate the quotes. Wrote a simple function to take a string and out a literal string to be used in `concat(outString)`

```js
const xConcatString = (sampleText) => {
  const splitText = sampleText.split('"');
  const xText = [];
  splitText.forEach((ele) => {
    xText.push(`"${ele}"`);
    xText.push(`'"'`);
  });
  xText.pop();
  return xText.join(",");
};
```

Explanation:
**xpath doesn't support escaping characters** , thus the only option is to use `double quotes` when string contains `single quotes` and vice versa.
But we can use the `concat` operator to split the string by any 1 type of quote you decide and wrap it in another. In above function I am splitting by `single quote`.

Also `.` works better than `text()` when finding xpath element via text inside it.
Thus from sample in the question,

```js
const sampleText = `Uses the "crow's foot" notation rather than classic ER notation to depict a relationship`

const xpath = `//div[.=concat(${xConcatString(sampleText)})]`
document
    .evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
    .iterateNext();
```

Tip: The quotes on output string from `xConcatString` will get confusing but its a comma separated list of string and each string element is enclosed in double quotes

Comment: you may need to add a blank string in the concat to make it work when there are no quotes `//div[.=concat("", ${xConcatString(sampleText)})]`